# actionscript 3 trace returns a blank function rather than a number

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a simple code that seems to be giving strange results.

```
var startPoint:Point = new Point(x, y); // a point
var r:Number = path[i].row + (-Math.floor((length * 2 + 2) / 2)); // just some math
trace(r); // the math checks out and gives a 3
var tey = startPoint.y + r; //this gives a really strange return....
trace(startPoint.y + r, tey); // this works, and then gives the strange return.
```

the return is

```
3
10 7function Function() {}
```

as

```
var tey:Number = startPoint.y + r;
trace(startPoint.y + r, tey);
```

the return is

```
10 NaN
```

IDE is FlashDevelop if you feel that information is important.

### Additional Info/Testing:

```
trace(startPoint.y);
```

traces as

```
7
```

#### :Number

```
var tey:Number = startPoint.y + r;
trace(tey);
```

equals

```
NaN
```

#### Number()

```
var tey = Number(startPoint.y) + r;
trace(tey);
```

equals

```
7function Function() {}
```

(excuse my poor post layout, I'm still inexperienced with stackoverflow's editing system and am working on making this a little cleaner)

Comment: Have you tried tracing `startPoint.y`? `NaN` is returned when you try adding a number to something that is not a number.

Comment: it returns a 7, i shall add it to the post. The trace works for everything I could think of, i tested and fiddled for a while. It only doesn't work when I try to add them together in the 'tey' variable preemptively.

Comment: It doesn't seem that `startPoint.y` is the problem, it seems that `r` is evaluating to `function Function() {}`, but obviously only in that context. Which is incredibly strange.

Comment: Hard to debug further without seeing assignments of `x`,`y`,`i`,`path[]`,`length`, contents of `path[i].row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue, it was with a part of the code that I appended out of my sample above.

```
var startPoint:Point = new Point(x, y); // a point
for ( /*for stuff*/ ){
    var r:Number = path[i].row + (-Math.floor((length * 2 + 2) / 2)); // just some math
}
trace(r); // the math checks out and gives a 3
var tey = startPoint.y + r; //this gives a really strange return....
trace(startPoint.y + r, tey); // this works, and then gives the strange return.
```

being var'd inside of the for loop made it act oddly when used outside so I had to move the var assignment outside of the loop and use as normal. A strange occurrence, but I should have knew better.

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce your issue.
Your problem is with the X and Y values on this line, probably more so the Y value.

```
var startPoint:Point = new Point(x, y); // a point
```

Try hard coding the X and Y to 0

Here is some sample code I ran. This worked as expected, so I will assume its the vars X and Y or something related to the "i" when you access path[i].row

```
var startPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0); // a point
var r:Number = 3; // just some math
trace(r); // the math checks out and gives a 3
var tey = startPoint.y + r; //this gives a really strange return....
trace(startPoint.y + r, tey); // this works, and then gives the strange return.
```